# Are there issues with using Cokin/Lee style filter systems with compact cameras?

Tags: filters, panasonic-lumix

I'm interested in trying Cokin filters (or a similar system) on my Lumix LX-5. Has anyone had success with this, and are there pitfalls to be avoided such as vignetting on wide-angle shots?

I've already used the threaded filter adapter tube, and screw-in filters. It's Cokin/Lee style of filters that I'm particularly interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Panasonic hasn't done anything proprietary with the thread pitch on the filters, you should be able to use holders like the Cokin system using a 52mm holder ring. Usually, most of the issues with filter holders and such vignetting is with wide angle shots, but I suspect that the adapter tube is going to be more of an impact than the filter holder. The rings for the Cokin system are about 1mm thick, so not very thick. You probably want to get the P series if you do, but I'd advise trying the ring out in the store before buying, just to be sure that you're okay on threads (I only say this because they list filters as accessories designed to use the adapter tube).

As an additional note to the Cokin system and ND filters... Stacked ND filters tend to result in a strong magenta color cast. Just be aware of that if you do try them out and shoot RAW for better correction. This is an issue only for Cokin as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks : The adapter tube gives you a generic 52mm filter thread, and causes no vignetting with a single "thickish" polarizing filter, even at 24mm equiv. I've used Hoya filters with no trouble.

Comment: @Roddy - That's the sign, I think, that says you can.

Comment: I guess it's the specifics of P vs A series that's the issue. I don't have anywhere convenient to try one, so I'm looking for first-hand knowledge of the combination.

Comment: @Roddy, that's mostly about focal  lengths. I advised P because of the equivalent range on your camera.

Comment: P vs. A has to do with the lens' *diameter*, not focal length. The "A" filters provide coverage for lenses up to 67mm in diameter at the front element. The "P" series can cover a lens up to 84mm wide. The Z-Pro and X-Pro are 100mm and 130mm wide respectively. The material in the corresponding filters in each size are the same. The price difference is based primarily on the larger amounts of material needed for the larger filters. An 87mm square has 1.5x the surface area of a 67mm square. The X-Pro series are almost four times the area of the "A" series.

Comment: @MichaelClark - It's both actually. For example, the A is for 36-62mm in diameter with a focal length over 35mm. The P is up to 82mm in diameter with a focal length of 28mm and above. The LX5 is 24-90mm equivalent, hence the P recommendation (next step up is overkill). I have that camera, I've just never put filters on it since I bought it for when I don't carry my SLR.

Comment: *If* the diameter of the front element is at or near 62mm, then there would be vignetting at FoVs that equate to focal lengths below 35mm on a FF sensor. It has been years since I've used my Cokin "A" system on the smaller lenses with my film cameras, but I seem to recall that as the diameter of the front element decreases, the angle of view available without vignetting gets wider. With 52mm filter threads, there may be some slight vignetting below about 26mm, but peripheral illumination correction should be able to deal with it. He should probably test it before committing, though.

Comment: On the other hand, if Roddy thinks he might be shooting in the future with lenses larger than the "A" size, then he should go ahead and start building a "P" series. Canon seems to be moving from 77mm to 82mm filter threads for their non-Super Telephoto premium "L" glass, so maybe even the "P" series will be too small.